# Insertion in BST

Tags: c++11, insert, binary-search-tree

I was doing a problem on insertion. This is the right answer.

```
/*
Node is defined as 

typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

*/


node * insert(node * root, int value)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        node *temp = new node();
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = value;
        root = temp;
        return root;
    }
   if(value > root->data)
   {
      root->right = insert(root->right, value);
   }
    else
        root->left = insert(root->left, value);
   return root;
}
```

The only difference with the solution I made is that in the if/else statements I did not assign anything. This is my code.
Node is defined as

```
typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   node * left;
   node * right;
}node;

*/


node * insert(node * root, int value)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        node *temp = new node();
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = value;
        root = temp;
        return root;
    }
   if(value > root->data)
   {
      insert(root->right, value);
   }
    else
        insert(root->left, value);
   return root;
}
```

I am not sure I understand why this is necessary because basically calling this function recursively will find a right place for the node with the data value.
Then, I create node with right data and just insert it there.
I will leave a link to the problem. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-insertion

Thanks for help!

Comment: So some deeply nested `insert` call finally creates a node and returns a pointer to it. If you don't assign this return value to anything but instead just drop it on the floor, by what magic do you expect the new node to become part of the tree? How will your tree ever grow?

Comment: After I create the node, I assign root to this node. If I understand correctly, root should point to the place where we should make the insertion before the assignment. After the assignment, it will point to the newly constructed node.

Comment: `root` is passed by value. Assigning to it inside the function has absolutely no effect outside this function call. Consider: `void f(int x) { x = 42; } int y = 1; f(y);` Here, `y` still has the value of `1` after the function returns, not `42`. The same happens with `root = temp;`

Comment: Yes, I know about what you have said regarding functions. But we are passing by a pointer; so, it should have an effect. I don't understand what does it mean to pass a root by value.

Comment: Consider: `int global = 42; void f(int *p) { p = &global; } int* q = nullptr; f(q);` Here, `q` is still `nullptr` after the function returns, it doesn't end up pointing to `global` (for the exact same reason that, in the previous example, `y` wasn't set to `42`).